# Nightmares about computers and Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups

I'm writing some code that does simulations of quantum field theory, and I came to the sudden realization that I hadn't yet written the part for the **SU**(n) Lie group. I know this group is a subgroup of **U**(n) and **GL**(n), but **GL** is already infinite and **U** is also infinite as far as I know. Computers don't deal well with infinite sets, so I was wondering if there was a way I could compute the generators of the n-th **SU** group without having to examine all of **GL**

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know if this will help you.  Dr. Todor Milev has worked on Lie algebras and wrote computer programs to study them.  Search for him on Google.  However, I can't promise whether he can help or he will respond.

Comment: Rarely seen "nightmares" in the title of a question, but why not ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Anyway $SU(n)$ is generated by transvections, which are relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much research, I've figured it out. I have written a program that finds the roots of the special unitary group's Cartan matrix. I can use this information to find the generator matrices.

Special thanks to Batominovski, I got talking with Dr. Milev and we were able to solve the problem.

Cheers!